# How to split mesh into several smaller ones with respecting UV map?

Tags: modeling, mesh, scripting, uv, modifiers

I am trying to split my low poly terain mesh and UVs into smaller pieces.
My mesh liiks like this:

[image 1 http://c2n.me/3AHCXzB.png](http://c2n.me/3AHCXzB.png)

I am looking for automated way to split it in several parts like this:

[image 2 http://c2n.me/3AHDc3d.png](http://c2n.me/3AHDc3d.png)

I assume thet this will be really easy but I am not artist and my experience with Blender is really low. Is there any easy way to make it (script could be better)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have a way. This is what I did, and it worked perfectly.

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh > Plane*.
2. Go to the *Properties panel > Object Modifiers tab* and add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Use these settings:

[image]

3. Key <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*, <kbd>U</kbd> to open the *Unwrap* menu, and select *Unwrap*.
4. Split the *3D Viewport* and make the new panel a *UV Image Editor*. Open your image in the editor.

[image]

5. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*.
6. Add a *Displace* modifier. Click the new texture button. Use these settings:

[image]

7. Go to the *Properties panel > Textures tab*. Load in your image from the dropdown menu.

[image]

You should now see your texture displayed on the plane in the *3D Viewport*. Note that you
       may have to adjust the *Displace modifier > Midlevel:* value for your texture to sit right near the
       origin point. I have to use *0.836*.

[image]

8. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*. Key <kbd>W</kbd> to open the *Specials* menu and select *Subdivide*. Key <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*. Change the *Number of Cuts* to *3*.

[image]

9. In the *UV Image Editor*, key <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>. Additional UV Editing may be required, but this should start you.
10. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to open the *Mesh Select Mode* menu and either key <kbd>2</kbd> or select *Edge*.
11. Select these edges:

[image]

12. Key <kbd>V</kbd> to *Rip* the edges.
13. Select these edges:

[image]

14. Key <kbd>V</kbd> to *Rip* the edges.
15. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to open the *Mesh Select Mode* menu and either key <kbd>3</kbd> or select *Face*.
16. Key <kbd>A</kbd> once to select everything.
17. Key <kbd>P</kbd> to open the *Separate* menu and select *By Loose Parts*.
18. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*.

Note that one reason the separated planes may not look the same as one intact planes is that the separation provided each plane with an additional two subsurf levels, effectively. You would have to turn down the subsurf to 4 on each midget plane to get the midget plane**s** to look the same as one large plane.

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way how I can add Smooth modification to this workflow? When I add Smooth modification and I split my mesh, than it always ends like this http://c2n.me/3AKshwc.png then I go back to from edit mode

Comment: @user3016214 Played with it a bit, and the only thing I can think of would be to apply all of the modifiers and then split everything.

Comment: This is problem for me, because in this case I will lost my UV and I need those grid UVs because I am using splat map to apply colors to mesh